# How Google Chrome knows my current GPS location and how to use it in my code?

Tags: google-chrome, gps

today i realize that some pages can locate me (im using a laptop with no gps built-in) using google chrome with a an very impresive exactitude, i know that using my IP you can locate me, but not with such presision. Now in [google maps](http://maps.google.it/) you will see a button on top of the yellow men (street view) who locates you using **google chrome**.

How does this work? There is an **API** to use that?

Comment: Just tried it and it located me with a precision of about 20 meters! Impressive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also possible with the actual HTML 5 Geolocation functions (only if your browser supports):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  alert("Not Supported!");
}

function success(position) {
  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
  console.log(position.coords.longitude);
}

function error(msg) {
  console.log(typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "error");
}

var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {  
  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
  console.log(position.coords.longitude);
});

navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
```

Greetings,
Sascha

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [help page](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142065&hl=en-GB)

> The local network information used by Google Location Services to estimate your location includes information about visible WiFi access points, including their signal strength; information about your local router; your computer's IP address. The accuracy and coverage of Google Location Services will vary by location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Firefox code that allows you to access the Google Location Service:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.9.1/source/dom/src/geolocation/NetworkGeolocationProvider.js

Enjoy!