# Can not get GPS from Google Chrome in Android

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, gps, android-gps

I have some code javascript for get GPS from browser.
It can get exacly GPS in: **Chrome (Window 7-PC), Firefox (Window 7-PC) , Firefox (Android 5.0-Smartphone).**
But with **Chrome (Android 5.0-Smartphone)** it can not get GPS.
My code:

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successGPS, errorGPS, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 60000});
} else {
    console.log('Geolocation is not supported');}}

function successGPS(position) {
latLng_taxi = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);
alert(latLng_taxi);}

function errorGPS() {
alert("Cant get GPS");}
```

Please tell me a about my problem and how to get GPS in with Chrome (Android)

Answer (score 1):

because my **phone** use Chrome(52.0) so it require **https** protocol for get GPS.

1. My host (on desktop) use http -> my phone cannot get GPS.
2. On desktop i use Chrome (53.0) but it can get GPS because Chrome running on my
   **localhost**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) if it can help you.

This API is supported not only in Google Chrome but also in IE, Mozilla, Safari and Opera, but take note that it has a specific version of browser that support this.

This documentation also provide you sample code on how to achieve this including Handling Errors and Rejections, Displaying the Result in a Map, Geolocation Object - Other interesting Methods and others. Just read the documentation link to know more about this API.

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343562/how-google-chrome-knows-my-current-gps-location-and-how-to-use-it-in-my-code) and this [link](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).